# Refresh ListView from update ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I am trying to bind a ListView (AllDocuments) to a List of Objects (DocumentSummary).  I am trying to do the binding using mostly XAML.  But I am having difficulty getting my ListView to refresh.  The call to get the data MainPage.xaml.cs.OnButtonClick is working just fine.  The object AllDocuments gets updated correctly with each press of the button and the data is good.  I just can't figure out why the ListView is not being update after I add a new item to the AllDocuments.  Obviously I am not binding something correctly.

I have provided the current code.

ViewModel Code:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace peMove.Maui.ViewModels
{
    public class DocumentSummary
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DocType { get; set; }
        public decimal Onhand { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }  
        public Color Color { get; set; }
    }
    public class DocsViewModel : IQueryAttributable
    {
        public ObservableCollection<DocumentSummary> AllDocuments { get; }
        public DocsViewModel() 
        {
            this.AllDocuments = new();
            this.DocSummary = new();
        }

        public void AddDocument(Document _doc)
        {
            //DocSummary = new();
            DocSummary.Id = _doc.Id1;
            DocSummary.Name = _doc.Name;
            DocSummary.DocType = "Part";
            DocSummary.Onhand = _doc.Onhand;
            DocSummary.Note = "Some note goes here";
            DocSummary.Color = MauiProgram.colorPart;
            this.AllDocuments.Add(DocSummary);
            Debug.Print("");
        }
    }
}
```

MAINPAGE.XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:peMove.Maui.ViewModels"
             x:Class="peMove.Maui.Pages.MainPage"
             x:DataType="viewModels:DocsViewModel"
             Title="Lookup">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:DocsViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <VerticalStackLayout Margin="20">
        <Button Text="Load"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="OnButtonClicked"/>
        <Entry x:Name="documentId"
               FontSize="24"
               Keyboard="Chat"
               Placeholder="Enter\Scan Id"
               ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllDocuments}" 
                HasUnevenRows="True" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                SeparatorColor="Black">
            <!--<ListView.BindingContext>
                <viewModels:DocsViewModel/>
            </ListView.BindingContext>-->

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto"
                              ColumnSpacing="5"
                              ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto" Margin="10,0">
                              
                            <!--Column 1-->
                            <Border
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            WidthRequest="40" 
                            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20,20,20,20"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                            Padding="12,6"
                            Margin="10"
                            HeightRequest="40">
                                <Label  FontSize="20"
                                    Text="{Binding DocSummary.DocType}"
                                    TextColor="#FFFFFFDE"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            </Border>

                            <!--Column 2-->
                            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" 
                                                 Spacing="5"
                                                 Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <Label Text="{Binding DocSummary.Id}" 
                                            HeightRequest="20"
                                              VerticalOptions="Start"
                                              HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                              FontSize="14"
                                              FontAttributes="Bold"
                                              TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding DocSummary.Name}"
                                            HeightRequest="20"
                                              HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                              VerticalOptions="Start"
                                              TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light='#99000000'}" 
                                              FontSize="16"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding DocSummary.Note}"
                                              HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                              VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                              LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                              TextColor="Black" 
                                              FontSize="12"/>
                            </VerticalStackLayout>

                            <!--Column 3-->
                            <Label Grid.Column="2"
                               Text="{Binding DocSummary.Onhand, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
                               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="Start"
                               TextColor="Black" 
                               FontSize="18"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MAINPAGE.XAML.CS

```
using peMove.Maui.Models;
using peMove.Maui.ViewModels;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace peMove.Maui.Pages
{

    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int count = 0;
        DocsViewModel docs = new();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.BindingContext= docs;
        }

        async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            DocId key = new DocId();
            key.Id1 = "Default";
            key.Id2 = "WF201B";
            key.Id3 = "000";
            ErpPart erpDocument = new();
            erpDocument = await ErpPart.LoadAsync(key);

            // This is working and returning a valid ErpPart.

            Document _doc = new();

            _doc.Id1=erpDocument.Part.Id1;
            _doc.Name=erpDocument.Part.Name;
            _doc.DocType = erpDocument.Part.Type;
            _doc.Onhand=0;
            _doc.UofM=erpDocument.Part.UofM;
            _doc.Value01 = erpDocument.Part.Source;
            _doc.Value02 = erpDocument.Part.Purchased;
            _doc.Status=erpDocument.Part.Status;

            docs.AddDocument(_doc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of a `List<T>`

Comment: This is what I have now.  Still not refreshing ..

Comment: you are also creating the VM in both the code behind and the XAML.  Pick one or the other.  I'd suggest removing it from the XAML, and then in the constructor of the page add `this.BindingContext = docs;`

Comment: Edited code to use suggestion, still not refreshing.

Comment: please [edit] your post to include the revised code

Comment: So the this.BindingContext in the code-behind worked but the XAML didn't.  Why??  Everything I am reading says to do as much in the XAML as possible.

Comment: You can do it that way, but you were doing both, so that your XAML was bound to one instance of the VM, but the code-behind was updating a different instance.

Comment: I can get it to work in the code-behind with the this.BindingContext.  But commenting that out and using the XAML '        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllDocuments}" 
                  HasUnevenRows="True" 
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  SeparatorColor="Black"
                  ItemSelected="OnListItemSelected"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Source,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.BindingContext>
                <viewModels:DocsViewModel />
            </ListView.BindingContext>' it does not work.

Comment: first, you generally assign `BindingContext` at the page level.  Second, if you want to use that approach, then you should bind your controls to commands in your VM instead of using event handlers

Comment: Same with you Jason.  Thank you so much for all your effort.  You are keeping me sane.

Comment: Jason, I have been tinkering around with this and can not get the list to refresh unless I use the this.BindingContect in the code-behind and removing the BindingContext in the xaml.  I even set the BindingContext for the ContentPage section of the xaml.  Are you saying that I can't bind VM elements in my listview without using a command which I need to define in my VM?  I can't just us {Binding Name}.  It just doesn't seem like that is what I am seeing in all the tutorials.

Comment: no, I'm saying that if you are using MVVM then you would generally bind VM commands instead of using event handlers in the code-behind.  You CAN mix data binding with event handlers, it just isn't ideal.  Without knowing exactly what you've tried its difficult to say what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: also, if you are setting the `BindingContext` in XAML, then you will have to cast `BindingContext` to the correct type in order to use the VM instance from the code-behind

Comment: @Jason I have refreshed the code after applying some things I have learned (i hope).  But it is still weird that I can not get the ListView to refresh.  I wanted you to see the current code.  Appreciate all of your help.

Comment: you are still creating **two separate instances** of the VM, one in the XAML and one in the code-behind.

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: In MainPage.xaml.cs I have the line 'DocsViewModel docs = new();' in the class definition.  This creates a new instance of the view model.  But when the InitializeComponent executes in the MainPage initiator it creates another instance of the View Model from the BindingContext (I think).  I think this is my problem, but if I don't define docs in the code behind, how would I call the AddDocument method at the end of "OnButtonClicked" to add the results to the AllDocuments list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating two separate instances of your VM, one in XAML, which your UI is bound to

```
<viewModels:DocsViewModel/>
```

and one in code, which your UI is **not bound to**

```
DocsViewModel docs = new();
```

then you add a document to the instance that the UI is **not bound to**, so the UI does not update

```
docs.AddDocument(_doc);
```

you can either, 1) get rid of the VM in the XAML and set it in code instead

```
this.BindingContext = docs = new DocsViewModel();
```

or 2, keep it in XAML and modify your code behind to use that instance of the VM

```
docs = (DocsViewModel)BindingContext;
```

Comment: Sorry Jason, I did not see this.  Yes, I **FINALLY** see this.  And I don't see an advantage to the keeping it in the XAML.  I still am using it in the XAML like your #2, and I get the items in the list, but it is not picking up the bindings for the elements in each Item (Id, Name, etc.).  I suspect it has to do with 'x:DataType="viewModels:DocsViewModel"' in the ContextPage.  I can bind the ListView to AllDocuments, but I can't bind the elements of each listview item (Id, DocType, Name, etc.).

Comment: I guess I would need to make each of them properties of the ViewModel so I can use them as Bindings

Comment: you just need to add `x:DataType` with the correct type to the `DataTemplate` node

Comment: YES!!  Thank you so much .. now to the next hurdle ...  Again Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shared, I found that you are confusing the use of  `in the code-behind with the this.BindingContext` and `MVVM`.

Based on the code, I created a demo and added some fake data to achieve this function.

You can refer to the following code:

1.added some fake data to view model `DocsViewModel.cs`.

```
    public class DocsViewModel//: IQueryAttributable
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Document> AllDocuments { get; }
        public ICommand NewCommand { get; }
        public ICommand SelectDocumentCommand { get; }

        //public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }

        public DocsViewModel()
        {
            this.AllDocuments = new();
            NewCommand = new Command(NewDocumentAsync);
            //SelectDocumentCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand<ViewModels.DocsViewModel>(SelectDocumentAsync);
        }

        private void NewDocumentAsync()
        {
/*            DocId key = new DocId();
            key.Id1 = "Default";
            key.Id2 = "WF201B";
            key.Id3 = "000";
            ErpPart erpDocument = new();
            erpDocument = await ErpPart.LoadAsync(key);*/

 // here I added some fake data, you can modify it based on your needs.

            Document _doc = new();
   
            _doc.Id1 = "01";
            _doc.Name = "doc1";
            _doc.DocType = "type1";
            _doc.Onhand = 0;
            _doc.UofM = "UofM01";
            _doc.Value01 = "value1";
            _doc.Value02 = "value2";
            _doc.Status = "status";

            AllDocuments.Add(_doc);
        }

        public void AddDocument(Document _doc)
        {
            this.AllDocuments.Add(_doc);
            Debug.Print("");
        }
    }
```

2.set the `BindContext` for the page in `xaml` and set the  `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllDocuments}"`  for the ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAddDocToListApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiAddDocToListApp.ViewModels"
             >

  <!--  set BindingContext here  -->

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:DocsViewModel></viewmodels:DocsViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <VerticalStackLayout Margin="20">
        <Button Text="Load"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"  
                Command="{Binding NewCommand}"
               />
        <Entry x:Name="documentId"
               FontSize="24"
               Keyboard="Chat"
               Placeholder="Enter\Scan Id"
               ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"/>
        <!--<Entry x:Name="documentId"
               Placeholder="Enter Document Id"
               TextChanged="OnDocumentIdTextChanged"
               Completed="OnDocumentIdCompleted"
               ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"/>-->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllDocuments}"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  SeparatorColor="Black"
                  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto"
                              ColumnSpacing="5"
                              ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto" Margin="10,0">

                            <!--Column 1-->
                            <Border
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            WidthRequest="40"
                            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20,20,20,20"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            Padding="12,6"
                            Margin="10"
                            HeightRequest="40">
                                <Label  FontSize="20"
                                    Text="{Binding DocType}"
                                    TextColor="#FFFFFFDE"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            </Border>

                            <!--Column 2-->
                            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1"
                                                 Spacing="5"
                                                 Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Id1}"
                                            HeightRequest="20"
                                              VerticalOptions="Start"
                                              HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                              FontSize="14"
                                              FontAttributes="Bold"
                                              TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                            HeightRequest="20"
                                              HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                              VerticalOptions="Start"
                                              FontSize="16"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Value01}"
                                              HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                              VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                              LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                              TextColor="Black"
                                              FontSize="12"/>
                            </VerticalStackLayout>

                            <!--Column 3-->
                            <Label Grid.Column="2"
                               Text="{Binding Onhand, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
                               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="Start"
                               TextColor="Black"
                               FontSize="18"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

Since we are using `MVVM` to achieve this, we also need to set the command for the Button to trigger the click event on the `DocsViewModel.cs` .

```
        <Button Text="Load"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"  
                Command="{Binding NewCommand}"
               />
```

Comment: Wow, I appreciate the effort to help me!  I will look into this example as I get some time this week.  Again, thank you!

Comment: This will work with the fake data, but the call to get live data goes through the Asynchronous ErpPart.LoadAsync(key) method.  I would need to make NewDocumentAsync a Task.  Will that work??

Comment: You can first recheck if you could get the data from `ErpPart.LoadAsync(key)` method and add it to `AllDocuments` correctly.